# Firebase API Key Hiding

Tags: security, firebase

I am new to Firebase. I have a little concern over its Information that might get Publically opened.

Can Firebase be used as a Server?

How to hide apiKey, authDomain, databaseURL and so on details?
Basically I am trying to build an app where every one will have to log in. user's login credentials will be stored in FireBase DataBase. And the other data that they will add, will also be stored in Firebase.

So my Concern is, If I simply copy and paste my apiKey and databaseURL and those data in any JavaScript file, how do I make it encrypt or hide when the app gets builded (Production build) after testing phase.

Comment: Firebase can't be used as a server. However, you can use Firebase Functions for server-like calls - https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Comment: There is no way (nor need) to hide your API key and still use the Firebase services directly from your app. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Comment: Okay. Thank You Very much! that was bit helpful.